# SoapUI goes offline after a while

Tags: java, soapui, permission-denied, socketexception

I am using SoapUI 5.2. When I Start SoapUI, it works fine but after a while, it goes offline and Startup Page keeps on saying 'The page could not be loaded'. The only time it get backs to work is after restarting the PC. I checked the log and found following stacktrace. I've tried forcing IPV4 as per few suggestion. But no luck.

```
INFO:I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
DEBUG:Permission denied: connect
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:262)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:290)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:220)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could be port conflict. Check the soapui logs. Might be that netbeans starts a web server on 8080 or javadb. Not sure how the startup page wouldn't work though. Maybe some proxy configs?

Comment: There are other colleagues that use it without any issues and without proxy configs on the same network. We prefer a solution that doesn't require proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Check active ports using `netstat -o` in command prompt, verify the PID(Process Id ) from TaskManager>>Processes tabs for Netbeans and Sopaui if it conflicts change the port of either one.

Comment: Strange, I do not see the PID of both programs in the netstat command prompt list.